# Java client-server interaction with NIO

Tags: java, nio

I want to use Java NIO for client-server communication. Several clients should connect to one server. The clients send a serialized object. The server deserializes the object and sends e.g. an integer back to the client.

Can somebody quickly show how I can do this right with Java NIO?

Thank you very much.

Comment: please show an example of what you've tried and what isn't working. as written, this question will likely be closed.

Comment: [Please read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider to use Java EE and remote EJBs. You can use an Application Server which uses NIO, if that is important to you (I guess most/ all do these days). E.g. have a look at Wildfly.

Using a Java EE Application Server will get you a more stable solution with less code in shorter time than when implementing the low-level socket handling etc. yourself.

Comment: Come off it. He needs about five lines of code at each end, not an entire JEE server.

Comment: @EJB as you're surely well aware, socket handling isn't so easy to get right (beyond a hello world app). This answer is about 3 years old. Nowadays in many scenarios you would likely use Spring Boot or WildFly Swarm rather than an application server and some REST resources and JSON messages rather than remote EJBs. But I still wouldn't recommend to write the low-level socket handling yourself except for exercise.

Comment: I repeat. Come off it. Five lines of code, not a JEE server. The age of the answer is irrelevant. There are dozens if not hundreds of answers here showing how to do it correctly. Your suggestion is preposterous.

Comment: @EJP With all due respect, this is just your opinion. I stand with mine: don't use the low-level APIs if you don't have a good reason to do so.